# RunTime Error 91; Transferring Data from Excel to Word Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I am having trouble with what seems to be something simple from what I have found so far. I am trying to link data from an excel workbook to a table on a word document through VBA. This is the code that I have found and changed slightly so far...

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFileExtension As String
    Dim strFullName As String

    strPath = "file path here"
    strFileName = "file name here"
    strFileExtension = "Extension here"
    strFullName = strPath & strFileName & strFileExtension

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFullName)

    'Set the text of the cell from Excel to the cell in the specified table in 
    'Word (the second table in this instance)   

    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text =  objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") _
        .Cells(2, 1)

    'Close Excel bits
    objWorkbook.Close

    Set objWorkbook = Nothing
End Sub
```

The initial errors I had found were not having the excel object library checked off in References and simple syntax errors. After fixing those I am now getting a 'RunTime Error 91 Object Variable or With Block Variable not set'. This error occurs when I am attempting to set the objWorkbook variable. I have these public variable declared...

```
Public objExcel As Excel.Application
Public objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Public objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Public objRange As Excel.Range
```

However, when I look up this error, all I find is that I need to declare these public variables. Not sure where to go from here. If anyone could push me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. Also, thank you for all the help so far, this website is a life saver.

Comment: You have declared the application variable, but have you given it a value? i.e. `Set objExcel = New Excel.Application`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub GetData()

  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim strFileExtension As String
  Dim strFullName As String

  dim objExcel As Object, objWorkbook As Object
  strPath = "file path here"
  strFileName = "file name here"
  strFileExtension = "Extension here"
  strFullName = strPath & strFileName & strFileExtension

  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFullName)

  'Set the text of the cell from Excel to the cell in the specified table in 
  'Word (the second table in this instance)   

  ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text =  objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)

  'Close Excel bits

  objWorkbook.Close
  objExcel.Quit
  Set objWorkbook = Nothing
  Set objExcel = Nothing



End Sub
```

Btw you don't need to add references if you use the `CreateObject` function as used above.

**You had a couple of issues:**

1. Did not define (set) the `objExcel` application
2. Weren't closing (cleaning) after execution properly
3. Unnecessary Public declarations of Excel objects